# Can we pass dynamic query in SSRS dataset?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have created an SSRS report with three parameters - Two mandatory parameters and third which is a search parameter and also allow blank/Null value.
I have made a dynamic query to handle three situations for a that search parameter

```
1.) Display records without passing value in Third parameter i.e. NULL value.
2.) Display records by passing single value in Third parameter.
3.) Display records by passing multiple values in Third parameter.
```

I am using below query:

```
 IF (@Parameter3 = '')
 BEGIN
 EXEC('SELECT  * FROM [TblName] with(nolock)
 where [Col1] in ('+@Parameter1+') and [Col2] in ('+@Parameter2+')
 ') 
 END 
 ELSE
BEGIN 
EXEC ('SELECT  * FROM [TblName] with(nolock)
where [Col1] in ('+@Parameter1+') and [Col2] in ('+@Parameter2+') and [Col3]  ('+@Parameter3+')  
')
END
```

Now when I executes this query in sql server after passing my above three different scenerios it gives result acoording to parameters passed, But when I tried to add this in my Report Dataset it gives error--[image]
Can a dynamic query be added into a dataset in SSRS?

Comment: The answer is "Yes", however you're really asking why it doesn't work. For help, tou will need to provide the SQL query that isn't working, the error you get (including the parameters passed to cause the error), under what conditions does that error occur, and perhaps a screen shot of your parameter page?

Comment: I am Using this query:    IF (@Parameter3 = '')

BEGIN
EXEC('SELECT  *
  FROM [TblName] with(nolock)
   where [Col1] in ('+@Parameter1+') and [Col2] in ('+@Parameter2+')
   ')
END

ELSE

BEGIN
EXEC ('SELECT  *
  FROM [TblName] with(nolock)
   where [Col1] in ('+@Parameter1+') and [Col2] in ('+@Parameter2+') and [Col3]  ('+@Parameter3+')
   ')

END

Comment: Can you edit your original question with :  you will need to provide the SQL query that isn't working, the error you get (including the parameters passed to cause the error), under what conditions does that error occur, and perhaps a screen shot of your parameter page?

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is missing an IN clause after Col3.

```
IF (@Parameter3 = '')
BEGIN
    EXEC('SELECT  * FROM [TblName] WITH (NOLOCK)
    where [Col1] in ('+@Parameter1+') and [Col2] in ('+@Parameter2+')
    ') 
END 
ELSE
BEGIN 
    EXEC ('SELECT  * FROM [TblName] WITH (NOLOCK)
    where [Col1] in ('+@Parameter1+') and [Col2] in ('+@Parameter2+') and [Col3] in ('+@Parameter3+')  
    ')
END
```

Without knowing anything about the datatypes for your parameters, this should work. Expect this to be problematic when more than one value is chosen in a parameter.

I am not sure that the SQL needs to be dynamic. The code below could work just as well.

```
IF (@Parameter3 = '')
BEGIN
    SELECT  * FROM [TblName] WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE [Col1] IN (@Parameter1) 
    AND [Col2] IN (@Parameter2) 
END 
ELSE
BEGIN 
    SELECT  * FROM [TblName] WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE [Col1] IN (@Parameter1) 
    AND [Col2] IN (@Parameter2) 
    AND [Col3] IN (@Parameter3) 
END
```

Good luck!

Comment: Yes above code works when we pass NULL/BLANK value in `@parameter3` and also when a single value is passed in `@parameter3`, but throws error when multiple values are passed in `@parameter3`. So is this possible to pass multiple values to this parameter that allows NULL/BLANK  values also?

Comment: The second query should handle multiple values better than the dynamic query. If you stay with the dynamic SQL, you will have to split the values in `@parameter3` using something like this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36378884/ssrs-2008-report-not-working-with-using-a-stored-procedure/36390454#36390454. This splitter UDF can be applied to non-stored procedure solutions like yours.